# How to return multiple columns using apply in Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, apply

I am trying to apply a function to a column of a Pandas dataframe, the function returns a list of tuples. This is my function:

```
def myfunc(text):
  values=[]
  sections=api_call(text)
  for (part1, part2, part3) in sections:
    value=(part1, part2, part3) 
    values.append(value)
  return values
```

For example,

```
sections=myfunc("History: Had a fever\n Allergies: No")
print(sections)
```

output:

```
[('past_medical_history', 'History:', 'History: Had a fever\n '), ('allergies', 'Allergies:', 'Allergies: No')]
```

For each tuple, I would like to create a new column. For example:

the original dataframe looks like this:

```
id text
0  History: Had a fever\n Allergies: No
1  text2
```

and after applying the function, I want the dataframe to look like this (where xxx is various text content):

```
id text            part1        part2        part3
0  History: Had... past_...     History:     History: ...
0  Allergies: No   allergies    Allergies:   Allergies: No
1  text2           xxx          xxx          xxx
1  text2           xxx          xxx          xxx
1  text2           xxx          xxx          xxx
...
```

I could loop through the dataframe and generate a new dataframe but it would be really slow. I tried following code but received a ValueError. Any suggestions?

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(myfunc(x['col']), index=['part1', 'part2', 'part3']), axis=1)
```

I did a little bit more research, so my question actually boils down to how to unnest a column with a list of tuples. I found the answer from this link [Split a list of tuples in a column of dataframe to columns of a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44758596/split-a-list-of-tuples-in-a-column-of-dataframe-to-columns-of-a-dataframe)
helps. And here is what I did

```
# step1: sectionizing
df["sections"] =df["text"].apply(myfunc)

# step2: unnest the sections 
part1s = []
part2s = []
part3s = []
ids = []

def create_lists(row):
    tuples = row['sections']
    id = row['id']
    for t in tuples:
        part1s.append(t[0])
        part2s.append(t[1])
        part3s.append(t[2])
        ids.append(id)

df.apply(create_lists, axis=1)

new_df = pd.DataFrame({"part1" :part1s, "part2": part2s, "part3": part3s, 
                       "id": ids})[["part1", "part2", 'part3', "id"]]
```

But the performance is not so good. I wonder if there is better way.

Comment: `df[['part1', 'part2', 'part3']] = df['text'].apply(myfunc)` should work iirc

Comment: You can also do `df[['part1', 'part2', 'part3']] = df['names'].str.split(',',expand=True)`

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't describe my question clearly. I re-edit my question. @Asish M I tried, but I got ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable.

Comment: Ah so it can return multiple rows for each `text` ?

Comment: Yes. The function actually sectionizes a text column. Different text could have different number of sections.

Comment: @GLP, see variations of my answer if that helps.

Comment: @GLP, updated my answer to solve the tuple problem

Answer (score 1):

The idea here is to set up some data and a function that can be operated on this data to generate three items that we can return.  Choosing split and comma-separated values seems to be quick and mirror the function you are after.

```
import pandas as pd
data = { 'names' : ['x,a,c','y,er,rt','z,1,ere']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

gives

```
     names
0    x,a,c
1  y,er,rt
2  z,1,ere
```

now

```
def myfunc(text):
  sections=text.split(',')
  return sections

df[['part1', 'part2', 'part3']] = df['names'].apply(myfunc)
```

will give

```
    names   part1   part2   part3
0   x,a,c   x       y       z
1   y,er,rt a       er      1
2   z,1,ere c       rt      ere
```

Which is probably not what you want, however

```
df['part1'] ,df['part2'], df['part3'] = zip(*df['names'].apply(myfunc))
```

gives

```
     names     part1 part2 part3
0    x,a,c     x     a     c
1  y,er,rt     y     er    rt
2  z,1,ere     z     1     ere
```

which is probably what you want.

Answer (score 1):

## Converting the tuple to new columns:

To convert the tuple column value to new columns, you can do the following:

```
df[['part1', 'part2', 'part3']] = pd.DataFrame(df['text'].tolist())
print (df)
```

The output of this will be:

```
                                                text                 part1  \
0  (past_medical_history, History:, History: Had ...  past_medical_history   
1             (allergies, Allergies:, Allergies: No)             allergies   

        part2                    part3  
0    History:  History: Had a fever\n   
1  Allergies:            Allergies: No
```

If the tuples in `df['text']` is varying (not constant 3 items), then you can concat as follows:

```
df = pd.concat([df[['text']],pd.DataFrame(df['text'].tolist()).add_prefix('part')],axis=1)
```

This will give you the same result as earlier. Column names will differ slightly.

## Converting comma separated values in a column to separate columns

You don't need to have a function to do this. You already have a pd.Series. All you have to do is split and expand.

```
df[['part1', 'part2', 'part3']] = df['names'].str.split(',',expand=True)
```

Output of this will be:

```
     names part1 part2 part3
0    a,b,c     a     b     c
1    e,f,g     e     f     g
2    x,y,z     x     y     z
```

In case you have odd number of values in the `names` column and you want to split them into 3 parts, you can do it as follows:

within the split, you can specify how many columns you want to split them into. value of n sets the split to n parts (starting with 0. If you need 3 columns, n=2)

```
import pandas as pd
data = { 'names' : ['a,b,c','d,e,f','p,q,r,s','x,y,z']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = pd.concat([df[['names']],df['names'].str.split(',',n=2,expand=True).add_prefix('part')],axis=1)
print (df)
```

The output will be:

```
     names part0 part1 part2
0    a,b,c     a     b     c
1    d,e,f     d     e     f
2  p,q,r,s     p     q   r,s
3    x,y,z     x     y     z
```

Or you can also do it as follows:

```
df[['part1', 'part2', 'part3']] = df['names'].str.split(',',n=2,expand=True)
```

This will give you the same result as follows:

```
     names part1 part2 part3
0    a,b,c     a     b     c
1    d,e,f     d     e     f
2  p,q,r,s     p     q   r,s
3    x,y,z     x     y     z
```

And in case you want to get all the values split into each column, then you can do this:

```
df = pd.concat([df[['names']],df['names'].str.split(',',expand=True).add_prefix('part').fillna('')],axis=1)
```

The output of this will be:

```
     names part0 part1 part2 part3
0    a,b,c     a     b     c      
1    d,e,f     d     e     f      
2  p,q,r,s     p     q     r     s
3    x,y,z     x     y     z
```

You can decide to do `np.nan` instead if you want to store `NaN` values.

In case you have multiple delimiters to consider and split the column, then use this.

```
import pandas as pd
data = { 'names' : ['a,b,c','d,e,f','p;q,r,s','x,y\nz,w']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = pd.concat([df[['names']],df['names'].str.split(',|\n|;',expand=True).add_prefix('part').fillna('')],axis=1)
print (df)
```

The output will be as follows:

```
      names part0 part1 part2 part3
0     a,b,c     a     b     c      
1     d,e,f     d     e     f      
2   p;q,r,s     p     q     r     s
3  x,y\nz,w     x     y     z     w
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't describe my question clearly. My column is not like the "names" as above, it is a list of tuples and the length of the list varies.

Comment: @GLP, see if the new update works for you. You need to convert it to tolist() and it will do the trick